# How do I find files lost since I upgraded to Catalina 15.0154?

Tags: finder, catalina, upgrade, filesystem, folders

I have a MacBook Air Catalina 10,15.5  When I upgraded to 10.15.4 however, I may not have backed it up my because now  I've lost all my documents except those created since the update.  All my photos, videos, music and other non-print media, however, are still there.  Not sure if this matters, but while I create my docs in Pages I always save/d them as Docs.  I actually am more computer savvy than I sound and I've spent a lot of time searching for answers.  What I can't do is program and I'd rather not spend any money, unless you can recommend a service that's worth it.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Where did you save all your Doc files? As if you did not have them in the user folder:Documents it may have been cleared in the install if you left them in a weird location.

Comment: "I may not have backed it up." Did you back it up, or didn't you? Do you have a Time Machine disk?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. I'm somewhat confused, you write you lost all your documents when you upgraded to **10.15.4**, but since your Mac is running **10.15.5**, does that mean the data loss occurred some months ago? Could you correct the Catalina version ("15.0154") in the title of your question?

Comment: I bought the MacBook Air late in 2019.. I can't remember what the original OS version was but the first version I upgraded to was 10.14.5 (That's what "About this Mac"calls the version. Everything was cool until a few weeks/a month ago when I noticed the files were missing , except for one folder. Everything I've saved since has been saved correctly. I upgraded to 10.15.5 just to see if that helped but it hasn't.  I have TM but didn't think I had to save to it all the time.Ii thought I just had to save and  could rearrange things later.  Are you telling me I may have lost everything?!?!?!